# deploying asp.net website on IIS giving problems why?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, website-deployment

i developed an asp.net site using forms based authentication, that site is working when i run from visual studio builtin server, but when i deploy it in a IIS server its showing following error when i tried to login

```
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

I am using asp.net default template but i configured user authorization through web.config file, like

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
         name=".ASPXAUTH"
         path="/"
         requireSSL="false"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="~/Admin/OrderHistory.aspx"
         cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false"
         >
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="Admin" password="adm123$"/>
      <user name="Administrator" password="adm234%"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

### Imp info

i am able to logon using the VS builtin server but unable to login using IIS

### EDIT

Hi after changing the process model identity to NetworkService the earlier error was gone but i am not able to login

Every time its showing wrong credentials error message

im using asp.net membership login control to get the username and password

its working in VS builtin server

Comment: you code must be trying to connect sql server database and the probelm is because of that , had you use membership provider?

Comment: after changing `process model-> Identity to Local System` its working thank you

Comment: @ImranRizvi hi i am using membership login control to get the username and password

Comment: @ImranRizvi i have a problem im able to get rid the error which i explained in the question, but im not able to login every time its giving `you entered wrong username or password` message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting to your live database from your local pc, this will clear if it is to do with the username/ password used by you or some IIS configuration has to be done.

You can also check this link http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2009/10/07/error-connecting-to-sql-server-from-windows-7-windows-2008-r2-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: after changing `process model-> Identity to Local System `its working thank you for your help

Comment: HI after setting this the error was gone but im unable to login to the site using valid unsername and password also

Comment: i am using Asp.net membership control for taking user name and password

Comment: Please check http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: im not using sql server as datastore for login, im using web.config only for storing users info.

Comment: hi i updated the question can you please tell me why im getting error.

Comment: Does your server name contains special characters? Please check section cause of link http://support.microsoft.com/?id=316112